# How to add multiple AND conditions on same columns on a LEFT JOIN query

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to apply multiple groups of conditions on a left join, for ex :

```sql
SELECT p.id
FROM project p 
LEFT JOIN project_data d ON p.id = d.project_id 
WHERE (d.field_id = 1 AND d.value != "") AND (d.field_id = 3 AND d.value > 100)
```

Here is my db structure :

```
project_data
+----+-----------+----------+----------+
| id | project_1 | field_id |  value   |
+----+-----------+----------+----------+
|  1 |         1 |        1 |          |
|  3 |         1 |        3 | 80       |
|  4 |         2 |        1 | SomeData |
|  6 |         2 |        3 | 105      |
|  7 |         3 |        1 | SomeData |
|  9 |         3 |        3 | 50       |
+----+-----------+----------+----------+
```

So what i'm trying to achieve is to return ONLY the project 2, who have a project data with `field_id` = 1 and a non empty value, and another project data with `field_id` = 3 and a value > 100.

But this returns an empty list.
I guess it's because I have multiples conditions on the same columns.

This seems pretty easy, but I haven't find a way to do that.

Thank you for your help!

[EDIT]

I found a solution, but really not sure it's the best one (please let me know if you have something better)

```sql
SELECT p.id
FROM project p 
JOIN project_data d ON p.id = d.project_id AND ((d.field_id = 1 AND d.value != "") OR (d.field_id = 3 AND d.value > 100))
GROUP BY p.id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT d.field_id) = 2
```

Comment: d.field_id can never be 1 AND 3 at the same time. Try OR instead.

Comment: Move the d conditions from WHERE to ON to get true LEFT JOIN result. As it is now, you'll get regular INNER JOIN result.

Comment: Note that tables have _columns_, not fields.

Comment: @jarth that's so true. "Fields" belongs to rows; "Columns" belong to tables.

Comment: Hello guys and thanks for you answers. I updated my question with more informations (and replaced fields by columns indeed).

Comment: There's no point in this being a LEFT join, just use an INNER join. Other than that, your edit is the way I'd do it, just be careful that it's not possible for two rows to have the same field_id (two field 1's for example). If it is possible, use `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT d.field_id) = 2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A working solution

```sql
SELECT p.id
FROM project p 
JOIN project_data d ON p.id = d.project_id AND ((d.field_id = 1 AND d.value != "") OR (d.field_id = 3 AND d.value > 100))
GROUP BY p.id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT d.field_id) = 2
```

OR another way with multiple LEFT JOIN

```sql
SELECT p.id
FROM project p 
LEFT JOIN project_data d1 ON p.id = d1.project_id AND d1.field_id = 3
LEFT JOIN project_data d2 ON p.id = d2.project_id AND d2.field_id = 1
LEFT JOIN project_data d3 ON p.id = d3.project_id AND d3.field_id = 11
WHERE (d1.value < 110 AND d1.value > 100) AND (d2.value <> '') AND (d3.value = '' OR d3.value IS NULL);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT p.id
FROM project p 
LEFT JOIN project_data d 
  ON p.id = d.project_id 
  AND d.field_id IN (1,3) 
  AND d.value != "" 
  AND d.value > 100;
```

In a `LEFT JOIN` environment, the most left table is the reference table. In your case it's the `project` table. The purpose of a `LEFT JOIN` is to return whatever data from the most left table regardless of it has a match with other table(s) after it or not. If you do a `WHERE` condition on table after the reference, you're just breaking the `LEFT JOIN` and turn it into a normal join instead. Unless, you're specifically trying to find non-matching data in the table reference.

[See some examples here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=efc32cbd0d8c226164ceac831b725b9d)

New detail suggests that OP is actually looking any matches from the second table; which, with the same query I suggested above, can be done by simply changing the left join to a normal join. Therefore:

```
SELECT *
FROM project p 
JOIN project_data d 
  ON p.id = d.project_id 
  AND d.field_id IN (1,3) 
  AND d.value != "" 
  AND d.value > 100;
```

[Updated fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e9ec6977cc184c45b1803764b501daec)

Comment: Thank you for answer. I updated my question to be more specific, because in your exemple it doesn't return what I need.

Comment: So, you do actually want all the columns to have values, right? See my edit.

Comment: No sorry... I want all the project who have 2  `project_data`, one with the first condition (field_id = 1 and value != '') and another `project_data` with the second condition (field_id = 3 and value > 100). I updated my question with a working solution, but not sure it's the best one...

Comment: Why is it not the best one? What is your concern? The way I see it, there's no problem if it's returning the result that you want. Unless, if there are other data variation that could make the query returning incorrect result or if you have so many data that this is not the optimal query in terms of performance.

Comment: My concern was more about the performance, and I was thinking there was a solution without having to count the matched found conditions...
I'll stick with my solution for now ! 
Thank you for you time.